# SBT Native-Packager: How Classpath are Published?

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager

I'm packaging my application with the sbt native-packager using Java application archetype and Debian format.

According to their documentation, the Java application archetype produces a [start script](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/index.html#start-script-options), which declares runtime classpath like the following:

```
declare -r app_classpath="$lib_dir/..."
```

I'm wondering where this classpath comes from and how the native-packager manages to get this classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Native-packager uses the `dependencyClasspath in Runtime` task and the dependent sub modules to build the classpath.

You can see the concrete implementation here:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/JavaAppPackaging.scala#L52

Cheers,
Muki